# More than one object in LinkedList node, comparing?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, priority-queue

Suppose I had a class like this.

```
class GroupOfFourInts
{
   int myInt1;
   int myInt2;
   int myInt3;
   int myInt4;

   public GroupOfFourInts(int a, int b, int c, int d)
   {
     myInt1 = a; myInt2 = b; myInt3 = c; myInt4 = d;
   }
}
```

If I were to insert these four integers into a single node in a linked list, how would I go about comparing those? For example, if I'm trying to make a priority queue using a linked list, how could I use myInt2 as the priority and insert the nodes in order by the highest myInt2 to the lowest?

Comment: For providing comparison strategy, you can implement `Comparable` and override its' `compareTo` method. For priority, you will need to use this `compareTo` for sorting your Linked list and then inserting to queue.